# Powershell Remoting: Enable-WSManCredSSP fails with : This command cannot be executed because the setting cannot be enabled

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I tried the following command to enable CredSSP:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer *.domain.local -Force
```

> Enable-WSManCredSSP : This command cannot be executed because the
>   setting cannot be enabled.

How do I overcome this error? What am I doing wrong? What is the reason for this error?

Get-WSManCredSSP

> The machine is not configured to allow delegating fresh credentials.
>   This computer is configured to receive credentials from a remote
>   client computer.

winrm get winrm/config

```
Config
    MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
    MaxTimeoutms = 60000
    MaxBatchItems = 32000
    MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
    Client
        NetworkDelayms = 5000
        URLPrefix = wsman
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = true
            Digest = true
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = true
            CredSSP = true [Source="GPO"]
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        TrustedHosts = *.XXX.local [Source="GPO"]
    Service
        RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
        MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
        MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
        EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
        MaxConnections = 300
        MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
        AllowUnencrypted = false
        Auth
            Basic = false
            Kerberos = true
            Negotiate = true
            Certificate = false
            CredSSP = true [Source="GPO"]
            CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
        DefaultPorts
            HTTP = 5985
            HTTPS = 5986
        IPv4Filter = *
        IPv6Filter = *
        EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
        EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
        CertificateThumbprint
        AllowRemoteAccess = true
    Winrs
        AllowRemoteShellAccess = true
        IdleTimeout = 7200000
        MaxConcurrentUsers = 10
        MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
        MaxProcessesPerShell = 25
        MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 1024
        MaxShellsPerUser = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GPO to create WinRM listeners?

You need to enable Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials for the WinRM client policy and add the SPN with WSMAN prefix.

Comment: At first I did all changes with Powershell and then I used Group Policy (gpedit). Is there a difference between both?

Comment: Not really. We can change these settings in either of these methods. Try the allow delegating fresh credentials on your client. That should resolve, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way
I was working on this problem almost two weeks and now I know that sometimes you can have problem with command `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer "my host"`

That is because command has no access for registry editing even when you are running PowerShell as administrator. I think it's Microsoft bug and I will create a ticket for MS Support

However there is workaround and you can do it by this script

https://github.com/bolvua/Enable-WSManCredSSP